# what are all the jndi.properties property names?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, jndi

What are the possible property names for a `jndi.properties` key?  I cannot find documentation as to what all the possible key names are.

How do I output the principal, credentials and remote key/value pairs for jndi.properties?

```
-run:
     [java] Sep 12, 2014 6:36:43 PM dur.bounceme.net.remotelookup.RemoteLookup run
     [java] INFO: java.naming.factory.initial   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory
     [java] Sep 12, 2014 6:36:43 PM dur.bounceme.net.remotelookup.RemoteLookup run
     [java] INFO: java.naming.factory.url.pkgs  com.sun.enterprise.naming
     [java] Sep 12, 2014 6:36:43 PM dur.bounceme.net.remotelookup.RemoteLookup run
     [java] INFO: java.naming.factory.state com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl

run:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 13 seconds
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/LegacyEJB$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/LegacyEJB$ cat src/java/jndi.properties 
java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtxFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
java.naming.provider.url=server.local\:1199
java.naming.security.principal=user
java.naming.security.credentials=password
remote=net.bounceme.ix.Foo
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/LegacyEJB$
```

as can be seen, not all the key/value pairs are being output.  Why?

For the "remote" name and value, should that go in a different properties file?

Main class:

```
package dur.bounceme.net.remotelookup;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class RemoteLookup {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RemoteLookup.class.getName());
    private final MyProps p = new MyProps();

    public static void main(String... args) {
        try {
            new RemoteLookup().run();
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RemoteLookup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getExplanation(), ex);
        }
    }

    private void run() throws NamingException {
        Properties jndi = p.getJNDI();
        Enumeration e = jndi.propertyNames();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) e.nextElement();
            String val = jndi.getProperty(key);
            log.info(key + "\t" + val);
        }
        Context ic = new InitialContext();
//        MyRemote mr = (MyRemote) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/Foo");  //
    }
}
```

to read properties files, has worked in the past:

```
package dur.bounceme.net.remotelookup;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MyProps {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyProps.class.getName());
    private final Properties jndi = new Properties();

    public MyProps() {
        try {
            loadJNDI();
            String name = jndi.getProperty("name");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyProps.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public Properties getJNDI() {
        return jndi;
    }

    private void loadJNDI() throws IOException {
        jndi.load(MyProps.class.getResourceAsStream("/jndi.properties"));
    }

}
```

more to the point, what should the key be named as for the values?

------------------------------------------------------edit-------------------------

java.naming.factory.initial=TO_BE_CHANGED_BY_USER 
java.naming.factory.object=TO_BE_CHANGED_BY_USER 
java.naming.factory.state=TO_BE_CHANGED_BY_USER 
java.naming.factory.control=TO_BE_CHANGED_BY_USER 
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=TO_BE_CHANGED_BY_USER 
java.naming.provider.url=TO_BE_CHANGED_BY_USER 
java.naming.dns.url=TO_BE_CHANGED_BY_USER

from:

http://www.pressinganswer.com/433577/how-to-access-datasource-in-geronimo-via-jndi-by-remote-client-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look in the documentation for each provider, in your case, the COSNaming provider, on the [JNDI documentation page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/index.html).

Comment: why is it COS and not RMI?  The intention is java to java, for remote invocation of an EJB.  Thanks for the link, I'm looking into it.

Comment: Because you're using `com.sun.corba.ee.impl` for a start. EJBs normally use RMI/IIOP which in turn uses COSNaming.